# FireDac adding underscore 1 to differentiate between 2 column names with the same name

Tags: sql, delphi, firedac

I have a select which joins the 2 tables, so there are columns with similar names from these tables, so now when retrieving the results FireDac adds underscore 1 to the 2nd column name to differentiate between the 2

```
Select * from Table1 inner join Table2 on 
Table1.id = Table2.id
```

When getting records from fields with similar names I would have to do this...

```
Dataset.FieldByName('Name').asInteger
Dataset.FieldByName('Name_1').asInteger
```

I would like to know if there is a setting to change the _1 to something else, reason I want to change this is that we used to use Interbase which added just a 1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such configuration. only option I can think of is not to use `SELECT *` but select the columns that you **actually** need with aliases for the same column names e.g.

```
SELECT Table1.Name, Table2.Name AS Name1, ... from Table1 inner join Table2 on 
Table1.id = Table2.id
```

or, if you need all columns from `Table1` and you *must* use `SELECT *` you can use:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.Name AS Name1, ...
```

See also: [Why is “Select * from table” considered bad practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234657/why-is-select-from-table-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: That is what I was actually trying to avoid because I need alot of fields

Comment: @Fero68, I do realize that. but I don't see any other option. What you want cannot be done AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `select * from`. Name the columns you want to fetch, define aliases for them and use their table names (or their aliases) to create unique names.

`select t1.Name as Name1, t2.Name as Name2 from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Name = t2.Name`

You will now be able to get their values this way

```
Dataset.FieldByName('Name1').asInteger;
```

Comment: I am just wondering. Is the addressing field like 't1.Name' a feature of FireDac?

Comment: Are you sure this would work in FireDac? this does not work with ADO and has the same behavior as described by OP.

Comment: @kobik. Exactly - that's what I first checked :)

Comment: I am actually trying to avoid using aliases

Comment: @Fero68 Why? Aliases help you solving your problem. There are good reasons to use them. Otherwise you'd need to name the columns differently in your database